# Error 0x80042001 when Using VSTO Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, visual-studio, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I get this HRESULT 0x80042001 error everytime I try to use VSTO to code for Excel Spreadsheet.
It will not load. I've tried several things such as uninstall VS and MSO, used cmd to fix issues, troubleshooter ect.

Anyone have this issue or can help me fix it.

I've tried several things such as uninstall VS and MSO, used cmd to fix issues, troubleshooter ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides *repairing* VS and MS Office, Make sure the `Visual Studio Tools for Office Design-Time Adaptor for Excel` is an active Add-in in Excel.

Also you may find the [VisualStudio Excel VSTO Workbook failed with 0x80042001](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VisualStudio-Excel-VSTO-Workbook-failed/10467902?sort=active) thread helpful.

Comment: It is not in he browse for automation where  you said. I downloaded the automation for VSTO and it still doesn't show. 
I went to the link you provided already last night and that discussion has been closed. I asked for it to be reopened. 

I've uninstalled reinstalled both Visual Studio and Microsoft Office, and did repairs on both. 

I don't get why it won't work. 

Is there a way to manually look for the VSTO install cause I don't know where to locate it and it is not in the add-ins folder per browse automation in Excel.

Thanks.

Comment: The add-in is required if you need to open an Excel spreadheet in VS.

Comment: Ok I have it installed -Visual Studio Tools for Office Design-Time Adaptor for Excel per the active applications add-ins. I shows installed at least. I still get the 0x80042001.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with a newly created VSTO add-in?

Comment: I got it to work finally after updating MSO for 3rd time. Thank you guys for you help. I at least go the VSTO adaptor installed with your advice.

Comment: Glad my post helped. Don't forget to mark the answer.

Comment: Ok, marked as answered. Once again thanks for your time and effort. I love MSO and VS/VSTO and want to learn to code for it. Microsoft products are great! I just like them better when it works>

Answer (score 0):

`0x80042001` is `hrInvalidXML` - make sure the XML you return from your addin is valid for the task at hand. Most likely the XML is not malformed, just not what Excel expects.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean. I can't even start a blank excel in VSTO.